# sharing canonical urls with facebook dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canonical-link

my app has mobile only content. It uses hosted urls to refer to the content (http://fb.me/CANONICAL_ID) that only opens in app. like the ones shown on (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api). After fetching the canonical url from my server. The facebook dialog box is suppose to share it like so:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
[content setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:canonical_urlString]];

[content setContentTitle:appName]; //ignored??
[content setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailUrlString]];//ignored??
[content setContentDescription:caption];//ignored??

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:nil];
```

[image]
when i share, the post only has the fb.me link and it ignores the thumbnail assigned above, the title and the description.

**Why can`t i share the link with the content attributes assigned?**

Any suggestion will help.

Comment: Are you using iOS native share sheet? If so then this will not work due to  limitations of the iOS Social Framework's APIs.